# Simple android multiplayer score keeper

Tags: android, multiplayer

I'd like to have an android app that would allow a given number of users to be "logged in" either as a player or ref. The players would just be able to increment their score, while the ref would have a screen that shows all player scores and alerts the ref with a tone/vibration when a player reaches a target score.

I have no android dev experience and in a perfect world I would just find an app that does something similar to this that I can just tweak. I'm not sure if this kind of functionality would depend on having a server or at all where to begin on learning the knowledge that would be necessary to create such an app.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a vague question... you will however need a server to keep track of all the scores - for example you can have an SQL database that contains all the users/scores and all the Android app is tell the server which user's count to increment.

Another alternative would be to use the Google Drive APIs - you can probably use forms or something to increment counts while the "ref" would have full access to the document.